# Disable “…misspelled” message from VoiceOver on iOS

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

How does one prevent “…misspelled” from being spoken by VoiceOver on a text field? Setting autocorrectionType to UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo doesn’t seem to make a difference.

If the iOS user types a misspelled word followed by a space or punctuation, Voiceover speaks the word followed by, “misspelled.” I want to be able to disable this behavior on a specific text field.

Comment: Just curious, why? Do you also ignore spelling for sighted users?

Comment: Yes, it is ignored for sighted users as well. If a word game is based on correctly spelling words, VoiceOver’s “misspelled” announcement poses a problem.


I would expect that setting autocorrectionType to UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo would disable the “misspelled” message, as it removes the red underline signifying a misspelled word.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to set `spellCheckingType = UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo` to get this behavior rather than `autocorrectionType`. Does that not resolve it?